# listing elements that start with a specific char in linux using sed command

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a way to list words that starts with a specific char using sed/grep commands only. the words could contain digits and function marks as well (if I use grep command I'm only allowed to use -v,c,e commands)
would love some help
thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this? [grep-all-strings-that-start-with-a-certain-char-and-finish-with-another-char](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277089/grep-all-strings-that-start-with-a-certain-char-and-finish-with-another-char)

Comment: What do you mean by "elements"? Filenames? Lines from a file? XML elements? Something else?

Comment: by elements I mean words, they could contain digits and punction marks as well and should start with a space and end with a space

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us a snippet of text you are wanting to parse, perhaps?

> they could contain digits and punction marks as well

Do you mean digits and punctuation that fall specifically within a word preceded and followed by spaces?

Comment: it's some story, and yea that's exactly what I mean